# Framework7 navigation not working

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I have this in my-app.js:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    closeByOutsideClick : true,
    init: false 
});

var $$ = Dom7;

// Add view
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main');

function avvia(info) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      //data: {info : info},
        data : JSON.stringify(info),
      timeout: 6000,
      url: "http://localhost:8180/api/",
      success: function(data){
          urlRedirect = data.urlRedirect;
          //window.location.href = urlRedirect;
          mainView.router.loadPage(urlRedirect);
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        myApp.showPreloader('Loading...');
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        myApp.hidePreloader();
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              // executed if something went wrong during call
              myApp.alert(error, ' Error');
              //if (xhr.status > 0) alert('got error: ' + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
          }
      });
}
myApp.init();
```

After my ajax call, i would like to redirect the page to a new page that is returned as data field in case of success.
My problem is that Framework7 navigation `mainView.router.loadPage(urlRedirect)` is not working, while standard `window.location.href = urlRedirect;` is working fine. How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your urlRedirect returning just the HTML required for an Ajax page or is it returning the html for a complete Framework7 app?  What I mean is, if you are returning more than the structure of an Ajax page the router won't know what to do with it and may appear to do nothing.

If you call loadPage(url), the url should only contain, for example:

```
<div class="page" data-page="about">
  ... About page content goes here
</div>
```

In addition, navbar markup, header/footer, etc but nothing else.